# Group/Identify Websocket Clients

Tags: java, websocket

I am about to build a small application based on websockets. I found this little library called java-websockets and if works just fine. My problem is now, that I have not found any way to identify clients and/or group them so that instead of broadcasting to all I can select a specific group to which I can send my notification. Would be great if anybody knows how to do it with this framework or knows any different framework which does the same it such an esay way. Thanks

Library: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is as below:

1. Specify group at server side
2. Create connection with specified group if only for server side triggering, or also pass it to client side and let it handled by client as needed.

Edit:

Just tried a 'handled by client' version, refer to [online demo](http://screencast.com/t/uc9VPj2k), [project at github](https://github.com/benbai123/JSP_Servlet_Practice/tree/master/Practice/WebServer/WebSocket/GroupConnectionsWithWebSocket) and/or [related article at my blog](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/07/group-connections-with-websocket.html)